# How to Start a New Project

Tags: plutus, set-up, create-new-project

Let's say I have downloaded all the necessary things needed to start developing on Cardano and I just opened up the terminal. I want to start building a new project. What are the commands I run.

Example -- If I was going to do this for React I would run the following command and start coding.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

What is the equivalent of that for Plutus.

Comment: Please take a look at this post https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/9648/2335

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `npx create-react-app my-app` on cardano unfortunately, but there is a [helpful repository](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-starter) that has the project structure necessary to start working with plutus.

So, first, you need to nix-shell inside the plutus-apps repo:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps # if you haven't already
$ cd plutus-apps
$ git checkout <current-tag>
$ nix-shell
```

The git checkout part just need's to be done in the first time you run this or whenever you change the cabal.project file. "<current-tag>" can be found inside [cabal.project file](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-starter/blob/d0f93f297008be3d209e5d7eeb3233b8198a6f76/cabal.project) (in this case it would be `plutus-starter-devcontainer/v1.0.14`)

So, assuming you are already on a nix-shell, it would look like this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-starter.git
$ cd plutus-starter
$ cabal update
$ cabal repl
```

Way longer than the create-react-app one, but that's mainly because of nix-shell, after a while you get used to it.

Comment: Why do we need to do the command git checkout <current tag> ? I am following the plutus-pionner-program and I have to do this for every week's folder too. Why cant we just run nix-shell and start up the client ?

Comment: Because plutus-apps is being constantly developed and so some syntax / features change from lecture to lecture

Answer (score 1):

If your app is fairly simple and all you need is to be able to send transactions to an address, send transactions to a smart contract or redeem assets from a smart contract then there is a `create-react-app` to get you started here:

[Create React App on Cardano Developer Portal](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/cardano-serialization-lib/create-react-app)

Answer (score 0):

inside the terminal you would be able to make a custom directory (or folder tree) using the commands `mkdir` and `cd` which make a folder and change the current folder your in respectively.

Doing this will separate your project files from the plutus files, but by running nix-shell your environment would still be the one required to compile plutus smart contracts.

To use this with vscode from the terminal navigate to your project directory and run `code .`. This should port your nix-shell environment into the vscode one, if it doesn't you may have to change some settings in vscode.

Between this and @Mateus answer your good to go.